# SQL store dynamic data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pivot

I have a table, which links to another table specifying the the value of a  key-value pair. The Value table then links to a table holding the name (key). The tables are defined (near enough) as follows:

```
---------------
Entity
---------------
EntityID
Name
Some other data

---------------
Value
----------------
ValueID
EntityID
Value

---------------
Key
---------------
KeyID
ValueID
Name
```

Each Entity can have many Values and each Value has one Key. Each Entity may not have the same number of Values. Basically, this structure is allowing me to add table rows dynamically, without modifying the Entity table.

I want to  do a select * on the Entity table, using the Key.Name field as a column header, and displaying the appropriate Value.Values

Is there a dynamic structure available in SQL that I can do an insert into for each row in Entity, then return a select on?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: This type of dynamic operation is very system-dependent.  What kind of database are you using?  Also, are you restricted to doing this within SQL, or can you use an external language that calls SQL?  The latter would make this a lot easier.

Comment: looks nice in theory - not nice at all in practice.

Comment: Why would you put the Key and the Value in different tables?  That makes no sense, and is guaranteed to perform poorly.  Also, you seem to be inverting the roles of the Keys and the Values, as they are traditionally defined in EAV designs.

Comment: @RBarryYoung it's to do with what else is going on in the tables and the application code. Performance wont be an issue, as each entity type (this model is repeated for different types of entity) will only ever have a handful of dynamic columns associated with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like you want to [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data. There are two ways to do this with PIVOT, either a Static Pivot where you code the columns to transform or a Dynamic Pivot which determines the columns at execution.

Static Pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select e.entityid, v.value,
    e.name EntityName, k.name KeyName
  from value v
  left join entity e
    on v.entityid = e.entityid
  left join [key] k
    on v.valueid = k.valueid
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for KeyName in ([name 1], [name 2], [name 3], [name 4], [name 5])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72063/3)

A Dynamic Pivot determined the columns at run-time:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from [key]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT entityid, EntityName, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select e.entityid, v.value,
                  e.name EntityName, k.name KeyName
                from value v
                left join entity e
                  on v.entityid = e.entityid
                left join [key] k
                  on v.valueid = k.valueid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for KeyName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72063/4)

Both of these can be placed in a stored procedure. If you post some sample data for each of your tables and then the desired result, it would be easier to determine the proper query.

Comment: I managed to modify your example and get it working with my DB. Many thanks for the help!